# S3 saving - joining multiple small files into larger ones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I currently have multiple EC2s, each uploading one .zip at a time directly to S3.

The problem is that this generates about 6 million PUTs per day:

- 3 million 64-128 KB zipped HTMLs
- 3 million 8-24 KB zipped JSONs

More exactly I'm bothered by the:

- cost of PUTs
- objects are stuck in Standard because of per-object transition cost and the 128 KB minimum object size

Before I reinvent the wheel, is there already a way of:

- joining these small files in larger ones
- uploading them to S3
- serving individual small files from the larger ones?

Comment: Can I ask why you have 6 million zipped archives with such small sizes? Just ruling out an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Because each small zip is a JSON with data about a single HTML file. They are further processed and accessed individually.

Comment: Do they have to be individual or can you put them all in one zip? So you process the process on the other side? Best way would be to zip them all up before uploading and then unzip very quickly at destination.

Comment: That's the whole issue, I still need to access them individually.

Comment: The only way would be to zip, unzip and then access them individually on an EC2 instance or something. There’s nothing built in to S3.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about other software. There is stuff using ORC/parquet files to store data on S3, but sure how they do it, could be generating more API calls than I do at the moment.